# PHP mysql_close within function stops DB queries from working on page

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a PHP page that references an include file to get database information.  That same page interacts with the database and I have a `mysql_close($db_connect)` statement at the end.

However, I also have a function that is referenced in the middle of the code.  That function lives in a separate include file and also uses the database.  I have `mysql_close($db_connect)` statements in the include file as well.

The issue I'm having is that any database calls that occur on the main page AFTER the function has executed fail because the database connection has been closed.  I know this may be a newbie question but should I just not close the DB connection in my include files or am I going about this all the wrong way?

Thank you!

Comment: "should I just not close the DB connection in my include files" you've answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_close() closes the non-persistent connection to the MySQL server that's associated with the specified link identifier.

Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

Check out this link below:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using mysql_connect and just assumed that I had to close it at the end.

Comment: You can, but it's not explicitly necessary if my memory serves.  It's been a while since I've written an actual MySQL statement in PHP as usually whichever framework I'm using will handle it automatically.

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, please mark it as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries - had to wait five minutes before it would let me mark it.  Seems I got downgraded because some people didn't like this question.  Sigh.

Comment: Don't let them bother you.  The only stupid question is one not asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally just connect to the database once at the start, and either manually close it at the end or just let the script's shutdown sequence end the connection.